# JavaScript PHP e HTML, utilização do onload

Tags: php, javascript, html

Fala galera, gostaria de saber se a lógica do onload está certa nesse caso.
Preciso que esse script rode ao carregar a página. Qual seria a melhor forma para implementar ?

**HTML e JavaScript  e PHP**

```
 <div class="col-xs-3">
        <span>Matrícula</span>            
        <input  type="number" onload="verificaMatriculaExists(this)" value="<?php echo $dados[0]->matricula ?>">                                                        
 </div>
```

O problema em adicionar diretamente seria que teria que acrescentar todo esse código dentro da view oque faria perder o sentido da POO

Acontece que esse onload irá trazer todos esses dados atrávez dessa implementação

***JavaScript***

```
//Verificar se matrícula já existe na base de dados.

function verificaMatriculaExists(elemento) {

    var matricula = (elemento.name === 'matricula' ? document.querySelector('#dados-matricula-1') : document.querySelector('#dados-matricula-2'));



    var matriculaValue = elemento.value;

    $.post("<?= base_url('pedidos/verificaMatricula/'); ?>", {
        matricula: matriculaValue
    }, function(get_retorno) {



        if (get_retorno == '0') {



            alert('Matrícula não existente no sistema, cadastre um cliente antes de prosseguir');

            limpaDadosCliente(matricula);

            document.getElementById('cad_cliente').type = 'button';

            document.getElementById('div_cad_cliente').hidden = false;

            matricula.hidden = true;



        } else {





            matricula.hidden = false;



            var json = JSON.parse(get_retorno);

            var cliente = json.cliente;

            var cadastro = json.cadastro;

            var pessoa = json.pessoa;

            var endereco = json.endereco;



            //console.log(get_retorno);

            matricula.querySelector('#numero-matricula').innerHTML = `Dados Matrícula ${cliente.matricula}`;
            //nome-cliente.querySelector('#nome-matricula').innetHTML = `Dados Matrícula ${cliente.matricula}`;
            



            //Bancos

            json.bancos.forEach((banco) => {

                matricula.querySelector('#dados-bancarios-matricula').innerHTML += `

                              <p id='teste'>

                                <span class='banco'>${banco.nome_banco}</span>

                                <span class='agencia'>${banco.agencia}</span>

                                <span class='conta'>${banco.conta}</span>

                              </p>`;

            });



            //Contatos

            json.contatos.forEach((contato) => {

                matricula.querySelector('#contato-matricula').innerHTML += `

                              <p id='teste'>

                               <span class='nome'>${contato.nome_cont}</span>

                                <span class='fone'>${contato.telefone_cont}</span>

                                <span class='fone'>${contato.celular_cont}</span>

                                <span class='email'>${contato.email_cont}</span>

                              </p>`;

            });



            //Anexos

            json.anexos.forEach((anexo) => {

                matricula.querySelector('#anexo-matricula').innerHTML += `

                              <p id='teste'>

                                 <span class='tipo'>${anexo.tipo_arquivo}</span>

                                 <span class='arquivo'>${anexo.nome_arquivo}</span>

                              </p>`;

            });



            //Atendimentos

            json.atendimentos.forEach((atendimento) => {

                matricula.querySelector('#atendimento-matricula').innerHTML += `

                              <p id='teste'>

                                <span class='data'>${atendimento.data_ocorrencia} ${atendimento.hora_ocorrencia} </span>

                                <span class='dado'>${atendimento.ocorrencia}</span>

                              </p>`;

            });



            //Históricos

            json.historicos.forEach((historico) => {

                matricula.querySelector('#historico-matricula').innerHTML += `

                              <p id='teste'>

                               <span class='data'>${historico.data_historico} ${historico.hora_historico} </span>

                                <span class='dado'>${historico.ocorrencia_historico}</span>

                                <span class='userDado'>${historico.admin}</span>

                              </p>`;

            });



            preencherDadosCliente(matricula, pessoa, cliente, endereco);

       

        }
    capturar = document.getElementById("nome-matricula").value;
    document.getElementById("nome-cliente").value = capturar;

    });

}



function limpaDadosCliente(matricula)

{

    matricula.querySelector('#numero-matricula').innerHTML = '';

    matricula.querySelector('#nome-matricula').value = ""

    matricula.querySelector('#apelido-matricula').value = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#cpf-matricula').value = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#rg-matricula').value = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#emissor-matricula').value = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#sexo-matricula').value = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#dt-nascimento-matricula').value = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#telefone-matricula').value = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#celular-matricula').value = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#email-matricula').value = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#profissao-matricula').value = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#cep-matricula').value = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#endereco-matricula').value = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#numero-matricula').value = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#complemento-matricula').value = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#bairro-matricula').value = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#estado-matricula').value = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#cidade-matricula').value = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#dados-bancarios-matricula').innerHTML = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#contato-matricula').innerHTML = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#anexo-matricula').innerHTML = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#atendimento-matricula').innerHTML = "";

    matricula.querySelector('#historico-matricula').innerHTML = "";



}



function preencherDadosCliente(matricula, pessoa, cliente, endereco)

{

    matricula.querySelector('#nome-matricula').value = (typeof pessoa.nome === 'undefined' ? '' : pessoa.nome);

    matricula.querySelector('#apelido-matricula').value = (typeof pessoa.apelido === 'undefined' ? '' : pessoa.apelido);

    matricula.querySelector('#cpf-matricula').value = (typeof pessoa.cpf === 'undefined' ? '' : pessoa.cpf);

    matricula.querySelector('#rg-matricula').value = (typeof pessoa.rg === 'undefined' ? '' : pessoa.rg);

    matricula.querySelector('#emissor-matricula').value = (typeof pessoa.emissor === 'undefined' ? '' : pessoa.emissor);

    matricula.querySelector('#sexo-matricula').value = (typeof pessoa.sexo === 'undefined' ? '' : (pessoa.sexo === '1' ? 'Masculino' : 'Feminino'));

    matricula.querySelector('#dt-nascimento-matricula').value = (typeof pessoa.data_nascimento === 'undefined' ? '' : pessoa.data_nascimento);

    matricula.querySelector('#telefone-matricula').value = (typeof cliente.telefone === 'undefined' ? '' : cliente.telefone);

    matricula.querySelector('#celular-matricula').value = (typeof cliente.celular === 'undefined' ? '' : cliente.celular);

    matricula.querySelector('#email-matricula').value = (typeof cliente.email === 'undefined' ? '' : cliente.email);

    matricula.querySelector('#profissao-matricula').value = (typeof cliente.profissao === 'undefined' ? '' : cliente.profissao);

    matricula.querySelector('#cep-matricula').value = (typeof endereco.cep === 'undefined' ? '' : endereco.cep);

    matricula.querySelector('#endereco-matricula').value = (typeof endereco.nome_endereco === 'undefined' ? '' : endereco.nome_endereco);

    matricula.querySelector('#numero-matricula').value = (typeof endereco.numero === 'undefined' ? '' : endereco.numero);

    matricula.querySelector('#complemento-matricula').value = (typeof endereco.complemento === 'undefined' ? '' : endereco.complemento);

    matricula.querySelector('#bairro-matricula').value = (typeof endereco.bairro === 'undefined' ? '' : endereco.bairro);

    matricula.querySelector('#estado-matricula').value = (typeof endereco.id_estado === 'undefined' ? '' : endereco.id_estado);

    matricula.querySelector('#cidade-matricula').value = (typeof endereco.id_cidade === 'undefined' ? '' : endereco.id_cidade);







}
```

Comment: Desse jeito não vai rolar

Comment: Tendeu, qual a forma correta para implementar @LeoCaracciolo? Acontece que estou trazendo um fetch atrávez desse onload que virá com alguns dados, mas pra isso preciso do onload que irá carregar automaticamente para vizualização dos dados

Comment: deveria colocar o evento na tag "body", nao num input...

Comment: Eis a questão o elemento que quero pegar para fazer o procedimento está no input e não no body, poderia explicar melhor @RicardoPontual

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo marcado com sucesso ! Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Vamos supor que `<?php echo $dados[0]->matricula ?>` retorne numero 12

```js
function verificaMatriculaExists() {
   //valor do campo com id = qqId
   var campo = document.getElementById('qqId').value;
   console.log(campo);
}
window.onload = verificaMatriculaExists();
```

```html
 
<input id="qqId" type="number" value=12>
```

> também pode conforme sugestão do @Ricardo Pontual

```js
function verificaMatriculaExists() {
   //valor do campo com id = qqId
   var campo = document.getElementById('qqId').value;
   console.log(campo);
}
```

```html
<body onload="verificaMatriculaExists()">

<input id="qqId" type="number" value=12>
```

> **funcionaria para um body com vários inputs ?** sim

```js
function verificaMatriculaExists() {
var z = document.getElementById("qqId").value;
var z2 = document.getElementById("qqId2").value;
var z3 = document.getElementById("qqId3").value;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
  x[0].innerHTML = z;
  x[1].innerHTML = z2;
  x[2].innerHTML = z3;
}
```

```html
<body onload="verificaMatriculaExists()">
<input id="qqId" type="number" value=12> 
<input id="qqId2" type="number" value=10000> 
<input id="qqId3" type="number" value=40> 
 
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example"></div>
```

Comment: Excelente respota, já tinha pensando nessa forma para conseguir implementar, achei que houvesse outra formas para resolver esse problemas, não quero copiar o input, mas muit obrigado pela reposta. Ficou muito bem estruturada.

Comment: O motivo para eu não utilizar essa forma de copiar e colar é porque eu já uso essa função verificaMatriculaExists em outras partes do sistema e por questões de engenharia e arquitetura de software precisaria criar uma função exatamente igual incluindo a cópia do elemento conforme foi explicado na reposta. Isso está fora de contesto e exigiria mais código

Comment: Conforme foi explicado por @LeoCaracciolo Ricardo Pontual comentou serviria para apenas um input dentro do body ou funcionaria para um body com vários inputs ?

Comment: @developerGo, se for direto na lata não fica bom?

Comment: Da uma olhada no tamanho do código que teria que adicionar @LeoCaracciolo acabei de editar a pergunta

Comment: @developerGo, eu vi

Comment: Oque você sugere que eu faça nesse caso ? @Leo Caracciolo

Comment: @developerGo funcionaria para um body com vários inputs ? sim